# Meaning of сровнялось

Tags: значения, словоупотребление

I found this sentence and was wondering about the meaning of **сровнялось**.
My guess: "He was all of 96 and a half, ...."

“Дедушка Джо был в семье самый старый. Ему **сровнялось** девяносто шесть с половиной лет, а это не так уж и мало. ”

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence the verb **сровняться** means "to reach the age of ..."
This meaning is colloquial, in neutral standard speech this meaning is usually expressed by the verb **исполняться**, so "Ему сровнялось девяносто шесть с половиной лет" means "Ему исполнилось девяносто шесть с половиной лет."

Comment: *сровняться* in that case definitely more correct, then  *исполнилось*, because *исполняется* counts full years(usual), and in direction towards future *в этом году(месяце) ему исполняется 97* . *Сравнялось* in that case just points on current fact, in situation where is hard to be sure about upcoming events.

Comment: @MolbOrg - Will you give any proof that _исполняется_ counts full years?

Comment: There is no proof. Russian Corpus has examples of non-integer number of years — admittedly, rare examples. "Исполняться" has a shade of reaching some threshold, which is not much used for half-years or something like "20 years and 4 months". but you can. Better, though, just use "будет" or "было". I would not advise anyone to use "сравняться" because it is a very rare word, and also is marked as vernacular and colloquial.

Comment: I have never heard it used with years, but Russian National Corpus has 13 such examples, which is literally 100 times less frequent than with "исполниться". Which probably correlates with the fact that "сравняться" is a rare word by itself (in the top of the most frequent Russian words it is somewhere about 18000-19000, very rare both in speech and in writing).

Comment: @MolbOrg For little kids parents are usually counting months, not years: "Нам исполнился год и два месяца".

Comment: @Artemix And everywhere else they usually say: "We are 14 months old". They usually count months till they are 2 years old, but sometimes you can find parents that are so carried away that they continue to count. And then you need to do the maths when they say: "We are 30 months old now"

Comment: And don't forget kids that are not yet go to school. They ask each other how many years they have to decide who is "cooler" - smarter, stronger, etc. In this case even half of a year matters: "Мне скоро исполнится пять с половиной лет".

Comment: @Artemix yes thats true about children and month count, just not wished to make it over complicated, also note you said 5 and a half year, counting half years also ok some times with the reason. children will count hours if needed ) . My opinion important in op's q is a fact : deal is about literature where using "old words" expected to be on purpose, to affect perception those who reads.

Answer (score 0):

my guess, the word "сровнялось" is applied to approximate the speech to the style that grandpas, grandmas do use.
and is similiar to "he become aged to the (amount of years)"